# Override method of C++ object like method of Javascript Object?

Tags: javascript, c++, oop

I was wondering if it is possible to override the methods of an object in C++ like doing it in JavaScript. (While "googling" it I did not find anything)

That is,

Javascript:

```
function Test(){
   this.doStuff = function(){
      console.log('Original');
   }
}

var obj = new Test();
obj.doStuff(); //"original"
obj.doStuff = function(){
   console.log('overrided');
};
obj.doStuff(); //"overrided"
```

C++:

```
class Test{
   public:
      void doStuff(){
         std::cout << "original" << std::endl;
      }
}

int main(){
   Test obj;
   obj.doStuff(); //"original"
   /*obj.doStuff ...???? */
}
```

Is it possible to do something like that in C++?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it would be possible, however not in an equivalent way, but by using C++11 function objects instead:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void originalDoStuff(){
  std::cout << "original" << std::endl;
}

class Test{
public:
  std::function<void()> doStuff;

  Test():doStuff(originalDoStuff) {}
};

int main() {
  Test t;
  t.doStuff();

  t.doStuff = []() { std::cout << "new stuff" << std::endl; };
  t.doStuff();
}
```

Comment: I get `ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'function' with no type`.

Comment: What's your compiler, and if GCC, are you using `-std=c++11` ?

Comment: I'm using `MinGW`, I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to achieve something similar, for example with lambda functions:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct Test {
    std::function<void()> doStuff = [](){ std::cout << "original\n"; } ;
};

int main()
{
    Test t;
    t.doStuff();
    t.doStuff = [](){ std::cout << "something else\n"; };
    t.doStuff();
}
```

But overriding means a different thing in C++. It is when you have a virtual function in a base class and you overrdide it with a function with the same signature in the derived class. Now when you call a function through a pointer or reference to a base class, it gets dispatched to the method that overrides it, based on dynamic type of the object. Example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "base\n"; }
};

struct Derived : Base {
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "derived\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    Base b;
    Derived d;
    Base& ref1 = b;
    ref1.foo();
    Base& ref2 = d;
    ref2.foo();
}
```

Comment: I get `ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'function' with no type`.

Comment: @Xlander You need to enable C++11 in your compiler (hopefully you've got one that supports it).

Comment: I'm using `MinGW`, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO having used both languages, it's a positive benefit that you can't directly do this in C++ (although it is certainly possible to replicate to an extent using e.g. function pointers or dynamic loading)

Changing what functions do at run-time is pretty confusing from a support perspective and tends (from my own observation) to be used as a way of providing in Javascript, facilities that C++ gives you for free such as inheritance and polymorphism)